# Binary search tree in haskell, comparsion

Tags: haskell, binary-search-tree

I have problem with BST in Haskell.
I guess I've problem with defining the "key" variable in Node(Uzel) to be Ord. But I absolutely don't have any idea more.

I though, if I once defined the "key" argument for the Tree type as Ord, it is valid and every use in code will get this information too.

Following code is not complete, but there is the thing I'm talking about:

```
data (Ord key) => Tree key value = List key value |Uzel (Tree key value) key value (Tree key value) | Null deriving (Show)

prazdny :: Ord key => Tree key value
prazdny = Null

najdi :: (Ord key,Ord k) => k -> Tree key value -> Maybe a
najdi k Null = Nothing
najdi k (Uzel levy klic hodnota pravy) = if k < klic
                then najdi k levy
                else najdi k pravy
```

When trying to compile i get this:

```
bvs.hs:9:49:
Could not deduce (key ~ k)
from the context (Ord key, Ord k)
  bound by the type signature for
             najdi :: (Ord key, Ord k) => k -> Tree key value -> Maybe a
  at bvs.hs:(8,1)-(11,58)
  `key' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for
          najdi :: (Ord key, Ord k) => k -> Tree key value -> Maybe a
        at bvs.hs:8:1
  `k' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for
        najdi :: (Ord key, Ord k) => k -> Tree key value -> Maybe a
      at bvs.hs:8:1
In the second argument of `(<)', namely `klic'
In the expression: k < klic
In the expression: if k < klic then najdi k levy else najdi k pravy
```

Lot of thanks for any idea!!

Comment: You can't compare variable `k` of type `k` with variable `klic` of type `key`. Try `najdi :: Ord key => key -> Tree key value -> Maybe value` as the type (and remember to return a value sometime).

Comment: Indeed, the error message says that `key` and `k` have to be the same type `(key ~ k)` and GHC is unable to prove that.

Comment: The question would be clearer to a larger crowd if you'd use English names in your code.

Comment: A side note, there's no need to have a separate `List key value` leaf. Having just `Null` will do nicely. Oh, and please do use English in your code, 99% of folks will have hard time understanding what `List` is doing here.

Comment: Thank for all - special thanks for Pigworker - IJW :).

Comment: 4 n.m. - sure, I know...it's better to use English instead of Czech in source code. But I'm quite new in Haskell (I call myself a .NET Developer) and this is for me a simple way how to recognize the keywords etc. and my own names O:)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that k and key must be the same type in order to compare them, but you declare them to possibly be different, so the compiler complains.  If you make them the same type it will type check.

Answer (score 0):

comment out this line and it'll compile:

```
--najdi :: (Ord key,Ord k) => k -> Tree key value -> Maybe a
```

Comment: Please explain *why* this is what OP needs to do; providing code changes without context or explanation helps no one.